# How to using "where" to dynamic build realation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Sry for broken english

I have 2 table fruits and berries and 2 model fruit and berry, both id are primary key, berries's id is a foreign key of fruits.

The meaning is if fruit's attr is "berry" then this fruit will have hp, atk, def. other just a normal fruit, they don't have hp, atk, def.

i'm tring "where" but not work, and i have no idea to add foreign key to migrate file

it's any solutions can solve this realation

### fruits

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id  |    name    |   attr    |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 123 | Blueberry  | berry     |
| 932 | Apple      | not berry |
| 429 | Banana     | not berry |
| 563 | Strawberry | berry     |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

### berries

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+
| id  | hp | atk | def |
+-----+----+-----+-----+
| 123 | 15 |   5 |   5 |
| 563 |  7 |  10 |   3 |
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

### Fruit

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :berry, -> { where attr: "berry"}, foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

### Berry

```
class Berry < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :fruit
end
```

Comment: Check the documentation for [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association). You need to add `fruit_id` to your `berries` table

Comment: Broken english could equally recieve help from our http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all bannanas are considered [berries](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=list%20of%20berries&oq=list%20of%20berries&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3715j0j4)... sometimes

There are at least 2 ways of doing this
 [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) (STI)
 [Multiple Table Inheritance](http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/)

In STI you only create the fruits table in the database, but add all the columns the Berry class will need. Even if this method will leave many blank spaces in the DB where fruits aren't berries, I recommend it because it is pretty straight forward and supported by rails. To use it change your `attr` column to `type` and add the `hp`, `atk` and `def` columns in a migration:

```
rails g migration AddAttrsToFruit hp:integer atk:integer def:integer
rails g migration ChangeAttrToType
```

Since the migration generator doesn't do magic like when the migration starts with the word Change as it does with Add, you have to edit the change function in the migration it creates to look like this:

```
rename_column :fruits, :attr, :type
```

Then change your Berry class to inherit from Fruit instead of ActiveRecord::Base

```
class Berry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fruit
end
```

Now when you create a Berry

```
Berry.create(name: 'Coconut', hp:100, atk:5, def:999)
```

Rails creates a the record in the Fruit table with all the attributes filed in:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Berry id: 1, name: nil, type: "Berry", created_at: "2015-10-14 02:38:09", updated_at: "2015-10-14 02:38:09", hp: 1, atk: nil, def: nil>]>
```

For MTI you can read the link.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from `robertoplancarte` - to explain a little more simply for you, you're looking to use a [`has_many/belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship:

[image]

```
#app/models/fruit.rb
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :berries
end

#app/models/berry.rb
class Berry < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :fruit
end
```

You can set it up in your database as follows:

```
#fruits
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id  |    name    |   attr    |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 123 | Blueberry  | berry     |
| 932 | Apple      | not berry |
| 429 | Banana     | not berry |
| 563 | Strawberry | berry     |
+-----+------------+-----------+

#berries
+-----+----------+----+-----+-----+
| id  | fruit_id | hp | atk | def |
+-----+----------+----+-----+-----+
| 1   | 123      | 15 |   5 |   5 |
| 2   | 932      | 10 |   3 |   x |
+-----+----+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

This will allow you to call...

```
@fruit = Fruit.find params[:id]
@fruit.berries
```

---

What `robertoplancarte` was saying was your current setup is pretty weak:

> 1. You're identifying which "fruit" is a berry manually
> 2. You're then populating another model with data which could be put into the first

The way around this is to use something called an [STI - Single Table Inheritance](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/).

This is a Railsy way to use a single model to define multiple *types* of data:

```
#app/models/fruit.rb
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type | name | hp | atk | def | created_at | updated_at 
end

#app/models/berry.rb
class Berry < Fruit
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
@berry = Berry.find x
```

This is more appropriate for your requirements; is somewhat advanced, but nothing a question on StackOverflow would be defeated by.